# How to display Alert Message Upon Negative Number

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

im a noob at javascript and was wondering how it is possible to display an alert message when the total value goes below 0. The page in question is here (http://cashmoneypaid.com/order-form-phones-work) and the script i have tried is below. Thanks so much for the help.

```
function checkTotal() {
    document.listForm.total.value = '';
    var sum = 20;
    for (i = 0; i < document.listForm.choice.length; i++) {
        if (document.listForm.choice[i].checked) {
            sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice[i].value);
        }
    }
    document.listForm.total.value = sum;
}
$("#total").ready(function() {
    if (sum > 0) {
        alert("We are sorry, but at this time we can not offer you any money for your   item");
    }
});​
```

Comment: Where is the markup? who is calling `checkTotal`? `sum` isn't defined in the ready callback!

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `jQuery` change it all!!

```
$(function(){
    var sum = 20;
    $('form input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        if (this.checked)
            sum -= parseFloat(this.value);
        else
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);

        if (sum < 0)
            alert('bla bla bla');
    });
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9SLq/)

You can also use this trick:

```
$('form input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var value = parseFloat(this.value) * (this.checked ? -1 : 1);
    sum += value     
    ...
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9SLq/1)

Comment: Hi Gdoran thanks for the fast response, i tried what u said but it does not work, the example you gave me, is that what i replace the checkTotal fucntion with

Comment: @DavidMaldonado. I added a live demo. You should learn some basics javascript and jQuery.

Comment: thanks for the live demo, definitely need to to brush up on the JS/JQuery. 1 last question: how would the demo you gave me be modified so that the sum/total value is in an input field that can be sent via the form? thank you so much for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: @Gdron, thank you so much for the help, after a little fiddling i got it to work

Comment: Hi David - you never came back and accepted this answer.  That's considered rather rude, as this person was nice enough to help you.

Comment: @BenjaminCox. Thanks, but you need to use the `@` so he will be informed in his inbox. Now I was the only who got this great comment `:)`

Comment: @DavidMaldonado - you never came back and accepted this answer. That's considered rather rude, as this person was nice enough to help you.